# reading SPSS file into R throwing error - error reading system-file header

Tags: r, spss

Lately, I sometimes get an error when reading SPSS files using `read.spss` from the `foreign` package:

> Error in read.spss("sample.sav") : error reading system-file header In
>   addition: Warning message: In read.spss("sample.sav") : sample.sav:
>   Bad format specifier byte (0)

I produced a tiny `sample.sav` file with just one variable and 3 cases that will cause the error. [Download the file](http://134.102.100.220/~mark/sample.sav) or use

```
download.file("http://134.102.100.220/~mark/sample.sav", "sample.sav")
read.spss("sample.sav")
```

Any ideas?

**My system**

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
foreign: Version 0.8-63

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Just throwing it out there, but have you tried the [haven](https://github.com/hadley/haven) package as an alternative?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns `haven::read_sav("sample.sav")` also fails

Comment: I tried both the haven package and `read_spss` from [sjmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjmisc/index.html) (former sjPlot-tool functions) and with both packages I could read your sample file w/o errors or warnings.

Comment: @DanielLüdecke. yes. I was wrong there. `read_spss` does the job (also see my comment in the `haven`answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$FL2@(#) IBM SPSS STATISTICS DATA FILE 64-bit Macintosh 20.0.0  ����������������������Y@24 Mar 1515:00:55electric paper                                                  �������������������VAR1    ���None�������������������������������–�����������È˝��������������ˇˇˇˇˇˇÔˇˇˇˇˇˇˇÔ˛ˇˇˇˇˇÔˇ���`

That is the header viewed in a simple text editor (TextEdit.app). So reading the help file for read.spss, one sees that it suggested using:

```
install.packages("memisc")

?memisc::spss.system.file
 memisc::spss.system.file("~/Downloads/sample.sav")
#-=----------------
SPSS system file '/Users/davidwinsemius/Downloads/sample.sav' 
    with 1 variables and 3 observations
 inp <- memisc::spss.system.file("~/Downloads/sample.sav")

 actual <- memisc::subset(inp, select= c(var1=var1))
 actual

Data set with 3 observations and 1 variables

  var1
1    1
2    2
3    3
```

The moral of the story: Sometimes is is better to read all of the help file. Since I have in the past read that same help page, I was surprised to find that it had been modified. In the past there comments regarding version limitations which now seem to have been removed.

Comment: David, I tried to RTM for quite some time now, but cannot figure out what the `memisc` equivalent for `use.value.labels = FALSE` in `foreign::read.spss` is, when my goal is to have a dataframe. Can you help?

Comment: An S4 object is returned. The `.Data` slot in the 'data.set'-classed object holds the values and there are 'row_names' and 'names' attributes. Seems that `as.data.frame` succeeds in returning an ordinary dataframe in the small test case you provided. Since I see no "value.labels", I'm not sure what problems you might be facing.

Comment: You are right, the comment was a general question... I add value labels to a new file `sample_labels.sav`. Running the code: `download.file("http://134.102.100.220/~mark/sample_labels.sav", "sample_labels.sav"); x <- spss.system.file("sample_labels.sav");
xx <- as.data.set(x); as.data.frame(xx);` I get a dataframe that cointains value labels, not the raw values. I would like the raw values though...

Answer (score 4):

I would use the `haven` package, rather than `foreign`, to read spss files:

```
require("haven")
sample <- read_spss("sample.sav")
View(sample)
```

You could alternatively use the `sjPlot` package, which uses `haven` to do its heavy lifting:

```
require("sjPlot")
sample <- sjPlot::read_spss("sample.sav", option = "haven")
View(sample)
```

Using `sjPlot`, you can also view the variable labels and values:

```
sjPlot::view_spss(sample)
```

Comment: An update to an old question -  `read_spss` is no longer in `sjPlots` but in `sjlabelled`